# Annotation Based Handler Mapping in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to understand how HandlerMapping work in Annotation based Spring MVC applications. As while working in XML based configuration we have one default and if we want to use other implementation then we have to define it in XML file as well as URL mapping strategies.

To understand HandlerMapping in Annotation based Controller application i came across to
DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping which used to be default before v3. 1 and now 
RequestMappingHandlerMapping is currently used. So I want to understand how to define this HandlerMapping if we are not using XML based configuration and URL mapping strategies. Another thing I came across was HandlerAdapter. So these two things are confusing me.

Please explain step by step when Dispatcher Servlet intercept a request how it find which HandlerMapping to use and how URL mapping strategies work in Annotation based apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can think that `HandlerMapping` determine a request/URL should be handled by which ways/frameworks (e.g use @Controller to handle ? Use JSP to handle ? etc)

`HandlerAdapter` drives the actual workflow of handling this request , containing the actual implementation of handling logic.

High Level Logic:

1. `DispatcherServlet` intercepts a request
2. Find out which `HandlerMapping` can handle this request. Refer to `HandlerMapping#getHandler()` for the matching logic. It will return a generic object (called a handler object) if the request can be handled.
3. Find out which `HandlerAdapter` can handle this handler object (By checking `HandlerAdapter#supports()`). If a HandlerAdapter can handle , it will handle it (by `HandlerAdapter#handle`).

Comment: Ok what I understand. Dispatcher Servlet will intercept all request and will consult with one of HandlerMapping implementation. In Annotation based configuration it will be RequestMappingHandlerMapping so what it will do, (will it locates all controller class and instantiate them and provide their  reference to HandlerAdapter) and what kind of responsibility it will delegates to HandlerAdapter.(is this HandlerAdapter who  responsible to call controller methods). I am confused between RequestMappingHandlerMapping and HandlerAdapter and URL pattern strategies they follow. In case of XML based co

Comment: In case of XML based configuration we explicitly define HandlerMapping and URL patterns strategies but how to define url pattern strategies in  annotations based apps.

Comment: Yes. `HandlerAdapter`  will actually invoke the controller method (in this case is `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`)

Comment: To customise the url pattern to `HandlerMapping` , check out `WebMvcConfigurer` .Normally , we let our @Configuration class to implement `WebMvcConfigurer` and override its methods for customisation.